# Identify a shooter part

Tags: part-identification

[image]Piece is very small looks like a shooter or something that would attach to a figure I have destiny halo Star Trek & a few misc cod & other mega pop culture figures but can’t for the life of me remember what this goes to is this even Lego/mega or did it maybe fall off one of my gundams lol

Comment: Need photos, please. Lego does not produce very many guns but piece identification ranges from difficult-to-impossible from a description. When you [edit] the post, you can add a photo with the "mountains and sun" button. You could also upload the photo to imgur and post a link to it here, someone will edit in for you if you have trouble inserting it yourself.

Comment: Photo uploaded hopefully can be identified ty

Answer (score 4):

This part is from Mega Contrux Borderlands CL4P-TP BL-U

[image]